# Verificar qual é maior usando uma formula em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu preciso utilizar essa formula e ler três valores e apresentar o maior dos três valores lidos.
Formula:

```
MaiorAB = (a+b+abs(a-b))/2
```

Estando os três valores na mesma linha de recebimento. EX:

```
MaiorAB = input().split(' ')
```

Onde e como posso utilizar essa formula?

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida? Por favor, edite a pergunta e adicione mais detalhes da sua tentativa e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga.. a impressão é que você simplesmente copiou o enunciado de um exercício sobre `Python` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal:

```
a = int(input('a: '));
b = int(input('b: '));
c = int(input('c: '));

maior = max( a, b, c );

print(maior);
```

[repl.it](https://repl.it/KUXA)